# COM Interop Exception when trying to read Excel file ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, excel, exception, com, interop

I have a very simple ASP.net 4.0 application that lets users read data from a common Excel file. The Excel file is situated within the application itself i.e. it rests on the server side in a folder right below the root.

I'm populating a Dataset with the Excel data using this code:

```
public DataTable GetExcelData(string ExcelFilePath)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string OledbConnectionString = string.Empty;
        OleDbConnection objConn = null;
        OledbConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ExcelFilePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        objConn = new OleDbConnection(OledbConnectionString);

        if (objConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            objConn.Open();
        }

        string resName = "'";
        string depName = department;
        resName += userLastName + ", " + userFirstName + "'";
        OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [" + depName + "$A3:Q10000] where Resource=" + resName, objConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        objAdapter.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;
        DataSet objDataset = new DataSet();
        objAdapter.Fill(objDataset, "ExcelDataTable");
        dt = objDataset.Tables[0];
        addSumRow(dt);
        objConn.Close();
        return objDataset.Tables[0];
    }
```

and after this I attache the Dataset to a Gridview and that's about it.

Now when I run the app on my local host there's no problem showing the Excel data, however, after deployment to our web server the application fails with this error:

> The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web >request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it >originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The specified domain >either does not exist or could not be contacted.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. >Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using >the exception stack trace below.

Any help is very much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: It seems like the error is NOT Excel file oriented. If you look in the attached code, the error is generated from Default.aspx.cs:239( SearchResult userInfo = search.FindOne()) at where I'm doing an AD look up to get username etc.

Answer (score 0):

few thing you may try

1>Disable anonymous access and enable identity impersonation
2>Ensure Excel file path is correct